# How to implement custom metric in UMAP?

Tags: python, numba

I am looking to linearly combine features to be used by UMAP. Some of them are GCS coordinates and require a haversine treatment while others can be compared using their euclidean distance.

```
distance(v1, v2) = alpha * euclidean(f1_eucl, f2_eucl) + beta * haversine(f1_hav, f2_hav)
```

So far, I have tried:

1. Creating a custom distance matrix. The squared matrix takes 70GB using float64, 35GB with float32. Using `fastdist`, I get a computation time of 7min, which is quite slow compared to UMAP's 2-3min -- all included. This approach falls apart as soon as I try adding the euclidean and haversine matrices together (140GB which is massive compared to UMAP's 5GB). I also tried chunking the computation using `dask`. The result is memory-friendly but my session kept crashing so I couldn't even tell how long that would have taken.
2. Using a custom callable to be ingested by UMAP. Thanks to the jit compilation using `numba`, I get the results quite quickly and have no memory problem. The major problem here is it looks like UMAP ignores my callable when the dataset reaches 4096 in size. If I set the callable to return 0, UMAP still shows the patterns of the original dataset in the graphs. If somebody could explain me what this is due to, that'd be great.

In summary, how do you go about, practically speaking, implementing a custom metric in UMAP? And bonus question, do you think this is a sound approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The custom metric in numba should work for more than 4096 points. That's a relevant number because that's the stage at which it cuts over to using approximate nearest neighbor search (which is passes of to pynndescent). Now pynndescent does support custom metrics compiled with numba, so if it is somehow going astray it is because that is not getting passed to pynndescent correctly. Still, I would have expected an error, not defaulting to euclidean distance.